# Why does react hook form errors does not render inside the useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

Outside errors are being logged while inside useEffect it's not.

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, dirtyFields, isDirty, isValid },
    clearErrors,
    reset,
    formState,
    getValues,
    watch,
    control,
    trigger,
    ...methods
  } = useForm();

  console.log(errors);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("errors", errors);
  }, [errors]);
```

I checked ChatGPT and stackoverflow but was unable to find suitable answer

Comment: Provide more details on how you wrote your custom hook, how are you setting errors. how you are assigning your custom hook to the form.